# Does calling keras "fit" multiple times shuffle training data in the same way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm training a model on some data (using [keras](https://keras.io/)) by calling the keras `fit` function, with `epochs=100, shuffle=True`. I want to call the `fit` function 10 times, and calculate the average validation accuracy for each epoch, over the 10 runs.

I hope that each call to `fit` will start with the training data in a different order, and shuffle the data differently through the epochs. Does this actually happen?

(If not, it's pointless to call `fit` 10 times as it will train on identically-ordered data each time.)

Comment: are you meaning you are looking to train 10 different models or train the same model and get the validation accuracy after 10 epochs? or you are looking to do Cross-validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to get **reproducible** results with keras you would have to set the same random seed before each experiment. Assuming you use the tensorflow backend:

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1234)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(5678)
```

If you now want **different** random behaviour between experiments you could explicitly set different random seeds. Regarding the randomness of the batch shuffle in the fit function, it should be sufficient to set the numpy random seed differently each time since keras uses **np.random.shuffle()** for shuffling.

Comment: If I don't set the random seed at all, will the shuffling behavior be identical across the 10 runs?

Comment: No, it most likely will not be the same. In the numpy docs they state: „If seed is None, then RandomState will try to read data from /dev/urandom (or the Windows analogue) if available or seed from the clock otherwise“. Meaning that it is set based on temporally changing sources. Unless you dont start your experiments at exactly the same time you can safely assume to obtain different random numbers.